# I am trying get three parameters of x, y, and z from this script but all it does is return one value that is not the dimensions I am looking for?

Tags: perl

I am new to perl and i am trying to get the dimensions which i think are given from the GeometricCenter method in this perl script. I used this script and it ran and returned only one value which i believe is a value called the gyration which is a paramter that helps determine the xyz dimensions. I thought this script would of returned the dimensions but it did not. Anyone know?

so i tried printing the values in the array xyz which i thought they were in. I tried this by using say but it said i cannot use say on an undefined value

This is the actual problem.
https://github.com/michal-brylinski/eboxsize/blob/master/eBoxSize-1.1.pl

Comment: First impressions: That script was written for pre-2000 perl.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your question boils down to "how do I print the values of an array?".

The answer depends on how you want the results formatted, but in the simple case of space-separated numbers, you can just do

```
print "@geo_center\n";
```